# Bar Chart Summarizing a Concatenated Column (or Multiple Columns) in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I currently have a column that lists a series of codes for the different business units we have, however, each entity can have more than one business unit affiliated with it (between 1 and 15 affiliations)

[image: Example of current structure]

[image: Example Desired Output]

I then have a separate list of all the affiliation codes so I can make a simple bar chart showing metrics broken down by affiliation code, but I'm not sure how to make the relationship between the stand-alone list of codes and the entity data.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks

Comment: can you post the picture directly to SO? I cant open it. However, I think you only need to create a table of unique business units with their respective codes. Then, link both tables through business units and use the codes variable to create the graph

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Can you mock up your desired end result without assuming which techniques may lead to it?

Comment: @Ivancito I can't make a relationship to it because the main table's column only CONTAINS MULTIPLE affiliation codes in one cell. I unfortunately can't embed the image because I need 10 points on SO to do so

Comment: @teylyn I added the desired output. I basically just want a bar chart with each bar representing the affiliation codes.

Comment: @SebastianHubard you would have to create a "workaround table". This means that you would need to create a table where either the codes or business units are unique, and then link it to the main data table through the unique variables table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalise the table with the three columns. This can be done with Power Query.

Split the Affiliations into separate columns, then Unpivot all but the Entities column. After that, build your result from this new table.